# How to Sort a List of Cameras by a Script in Unity using OrderByDescending?

Tags: linq, sorting, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a list of cameras that sorts itself based on a number held by a script that each camera has. Why is this code not functioning?

`cams = cams.OrderByDescending(cams => cams.GetComponent<cameraLocator>().cameraZone) ;`

Camera Zone is the ID number I want to sort by, cams is the list to be sorted.

Comment: I've further attempted to make this work by doing the following, still to no avail.

`cams.AddRange(FindObjectsOfType<Camera>());`
`cams.OrderBy(o => o.GetComponent<cameraLocator>().cameraZone);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt was almost correct. You still need to convert the `IOrderdEnumerable` back to a list.

```csharp
cams = cams.OrderByDescending(cams => cams.GetComponent<cameraLocator>().cameraZone).ToList();
```

Comment: Damn I was close! Thanks so much for the quick response!